# Join records with lowest value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, users and survey. I want query the table user and to join the table survey in a way that only the survey record with the lowest value is returned for each record in user table. 
I want to avoid subqueries and temporary tables.

table users:

```
--------------
| uid | name |
--------------
| 1  | mike  |
| 2  | john  |
| 3  | bill  |
--------------
```

table survey:

```
----------------------
| id | uid  | value  |
----------------------
| 1  | 3    | 9     |
| 2  | 3    | 5     |
| 3  | 1    | 3     |
| 4  | 1    | 7     |
| 5  | 1    | 2     |
| 6  | 2    | 4     |
| 7  | 2    | 9     |
| 8  | 1    | 0     |
| 9  | 2    | 5     |
---------------------
```

expected output:

```
---------------------
| id | name | value |
---------------------
| 8  | mike | 0     |
| 2  | bill | 5     |
| 6  | john | 4     |
---------------------
```

What kind of JOIn should I do, or how should I write the query?

Comment: I would use a subquery to return the desired records from the survey table and join that to the user table

Comment: The table may have up to a million records. Wouldn't a sub-query turn it very slow?

Comment: that probably depends on what indexes are in place and the database server specification

Comment: exists clause is optimized about reduce scan of table in subquery

Answer (score 0):

The following query gets all rows with minimum value (doesn't exist another survey with value under the selected value)

Try this:

```
SELECT u.*, s.value
FROM survey s
JOIN users u
    ON s.uid = u.uid
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'maximum'
    FROM survey s2
    WHERE s2.uid = s.uid
    AND s2.value < s.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
   select s.id, u.name, y.min_value 
    from
    (
      select uid, min(value) as min_value 
      from survey 
      group by uid 
    ) y 
    join survey s 
      on s.value = y.min_value 
      and s.uid = y.uid
    join user u 
      on u.uid = y.uid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
SELECT * FROM SURVEY S
INNER JOIN  USERS U
ON S.UID=U.UID
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.UID ORDER BY S.VALUE1 ASC )=1;
```

Comment: The question is about MySQL. This doesn't look like MySQL at all.

Comment: SEL main. ID,main.UID,main.VALUE1 FROM (
SEL  S.ID,S.UID,S.VALUE1,COUNT(*) AS ROW_NUMBERS   
FROM SURVEY S
INNER JOIN  SURVEY B
  ON S.UID=B.UID
AND S.VALUE1>=B.VALUE1
GROUP BY S.ID,S.UID,S.VALUE1 )main
INNER JOIN USERS U
  ON main.UID=u.UID AND ROW_NUMBERS =1
  
  Please Marked it AS answered